# UIDatePicker setMinimumDate and setMaximumDate sets null

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have no idea why this extremely basic piece of code sets null values.

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:currentTime];
[datePicker setMaximumDate:[currentTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:kSecondsInYear]];
NSLog(@"cur: %@, min: %@, max: %@",currentTime,datePicker.minimumDate,datePicker.maximumDate);
```

Output: cur: 2011-09-09 16:18:18 GMT, min: (null), max: (null)

Comment: Have you checked datePicker is not nil? Log datePicker to check it’s set up OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, I was setting the min/max date in the initwithnib method. When I changed it to the viewDidLoad method it worked fine. whoops.

Comment: There's a funny detail about maxDate: The dates out of range are still visible but displayed in dark grey (disabled), not hidden.

Answer (score 5):

Given that the following works fine, the issue is definitely with datePicker.

```
UIDatePicker* datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
NSLog(@"DatePicker: %@", datePicker);
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:currentTime];
[datePicker setMaximumDate:[currentTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:40000]];
NSLog(@"cur: %@, min: %@, max: %@",currentTime,datePicker.minimumDate,datePicker.maximumDate);
```

If you add `NSLog(@"DatePicker: %@", datePicker);` to your code snippet it should report something a bit like: `DatePicker: <UIDatePicker: 0x4b36740; frame = (0 0; 320 216); layer = <CALayer: 0x4b33940>>`. If it returns `(null)` (which I very strongly suspect) then it's either not created programmatically or it's not hooked up in Interface Builder.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but I ended up answering my own question.